# Configuring Report Server 2016

Tags: reporting-services, configuration, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I configured SSRS in Native Mode and expected to be able to view report manager via my URL. But the image below was what I get, with no access to the "home" link where I could set up permission. What do I need to do to rectify this?

[image]

If I click on "Report Manager", renamed "Web Portal URL" in 2016 version, I get the error below

Service Unavailable

HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved the issue by following the instructions on this blog post:
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/ssrs-http-error-503-service-unavailable-badrane-derbazi